# Rails find by sql escape colon character

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a SQL query on a model with a value that has a colon ':' in it.

Something like:

```
Model.find_by_sql([SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 ='some:value'], params)
```

This causes the following error:

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid

Any one know how to properly escape the colon ':' in the value text to field2 above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub!(':','\\:\\')` on value should work.

Answer (score 4):

Use where, it will make the code shorter:

```
Model.where("field1 = ? AND field2 ='some:value']", params)
```

Concrete example:

```
1.9.3-head :024 > Tag.where('created_at <= ? and name = "some:value"', Time.now)
  Tag Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (created_at <= '2012-04-23 18:06:54.967319' and name = "some:value")
 => [#<Tag id: 2419, name: "some:value", created_at: "2012-04-23 18:06:35", updated_at: "2012-04-23 18:06:35">]
```